# Php app uses <?= $var ?> format...doesn't work locally

Tags: php, syntax, view, echo

I'm not a huge php guy, but I can muddle through just about anything.  I've worked on a number of php apps in the past, but I don't really remember much.  As a favor for a friend I'm trying to help them trace a problem in a php app.  I got it set up on my machine (osx.6) php Entropy 5.3.3 apache.

It seems to run for the most part, but I'm having problems with the admin login...noticed that it wasn't logging in, giving an error or anything.

Anyway, my specific question deals with a line I am looking at where login errors are dumped to the view:

This outputs nothing, even when I set the value explicity Eg:

```
<?php $problem="There is a problem."?>
<?= $problem ?>
```

However it does work if I say:

```
<?php $problem="There is a problem."?>
<?php echo ($problem); ?>
```

This makes me wonder if the problems I'm having testing the app locally are due to some mods not being loaded, or a php version issue?

What's the diff between these syntaxes, and why would one work and the other not?

I've tried googling this...but I guess I'm not really sharp today...

Comment: I would recommend not relying on short tags. It can be convenient, but it makes your code less portable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) option in php.ini.

Comment: Also note that short_open_tag has been slated for removal for ages and is discouraged.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, Carpetsmoker.  It seems like there should be a deprecation warning in the manual.

Comment: Yeah, this app is a piece of garbage.  I've been working on other issues getting it running, and they are all because the original developer coded this thing for php3 (I'm guessing).  Couldn't login cause he's using $HTTP_POST_VARS (never even heard of that).  Thought it was me...looks like it's them.

Comment: The short_open_tag issue is a controversial one. Proponents of removal claim it's ugly and conflicts with XML's <? ... Opponents claim it'll make a lot of lived difficult because *a lot* of code uses it ... Actually, it seems to be "undeprecated" now: http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?7,115637 ... Plans for PHP6 change(d) so often it's hard to keep track ... :-/